# How to get the float value of Sympy's physical quantity?

Tags: python, sympy

For example, I have value `a`.

```
import sympy.physics.units as u

a = 133.05*u.kg/u.m
```

I want to convert this physical quantity to a float value, and the only way I know is `float(a/(u.kg/u.m))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `a.args` to get the required information. It returns a tuple containing first the numerical value and then the units. Example:

```
import sympy.physics.units as u
a = 133.05*u.kg/u.m
print(a.args[0])
print(type(float(a.args[0])))
```

Comment: You are right! strange thinks happen here...For example, I answered the question first and my answer is correct and works. Actually, is the same. I'd appreciate a comment to explain why that's better :)

Comment: Well, the approaches differ quite a bit: converting to string and doing string operations or using sympy's built-in finctionality. So the OP decided which approach he likes best and probably serves his needs better. He might be working on lots and lots of variables and found this method faster. Or he likes the additional benefit of easily getting the units seperatedly without resorting to another string operation.

Comment: Great job! Thank you!

Comment: doesn't work if it's multiplied by pi or other mathematical constant

Comment: @Rainb indeed, you would have to convert to floating point first. For example one could use `print(sympy.nfloat(a).args[0])`. Of course, in this case do not forget to `import sympy` first.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`as_coeff_Mul`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.expr.Expr.as_coeff_Mul) like this:

```
>>> a = 133.05*u.kg/u.m
>>> a.as_coeff_Mul()
(133.05, kg/m)
```

So the float value would be

```
>>> a.as_coeff_Mul()[0]
133.05
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the expression's unit or physical quantity, the following is the most reliable way I've found so far to get its magnitude as float.

### Case 1: You know the expression's unit

```py
def to_float(expr, expr_unit):
    return float(expr / expr_unit)
```

Example:

```py
import sympy.physics.units as un

flow_rate = 50 * un.m ** 3 / un.h
unit = un.m ** 3 / un.h

print(to_float(flow_rate, unit))
# 50.0
```

### Case 2: You only know which physical quantity was measured

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_physical_quantities

```py
from sympy.physics.units import convert_to

def to_float_as(expr, unit):
    converted = convert_to(expr, unit)
    return to_float(converted, unit)
```

Example:

Let's say you have multiple measurements in multiple units, but all measure length, and you are interested in summing them.

```py
from functools import partial
import sympy.physics.units as un

measurements = [
    50 * un.m,
    3 * un.km,
    2.5 * un.mi,
]

sum_in_meters = sum(map(partial(to_float_as, unit=un.m), measurements))

print(sum_in_meters)
# ~7073.36
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the desired units, I've found that dividing by those and then using `quantity_simplify` tends to work reliably well.

```py
import sympy.physics.units as u
from sympy.physics.units.util import quantity_simplify

a = 133.05 * u.kg/ u.m

def extract_magnitude(expr, units):
  return quantity_simplify(expr / units)

extract_magnitude(a, u.kg / u.m)  # => 133.05
extract_magnitude(a, u.grams / u.centimeter) # => 1330.5
```